# Saving login credentials

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

How to save the login credentials on the login page so that I don't have to keep on entering the email address and password. Any particular code for that? I tried searching on the web, however, they all have different. I tried these but the UserDefaults doesn't work. Everytime I click on the app, it asks me to enter the email address and password.

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "TEXT_KEY")
                           UserDefaults.standard.set(password, forKey: "TEXT_KEY")
```

Comment: Don't save login credentials in user defaults use keychain that is its purpose. UserDefaults is the most insecure storage. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services

Answer (score 1):

UserDefaults is an insecure way to store data, and I wouldn't suggest it for  login credential storage. However, it looks like you're trying to set both your email and password variables to TEXT_KEY, so I would suggest something like below.

```swift
//Setting code
UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "userEmail")
UserDefaults.standard.set(password, forKey: "userPassword")

//Fetch code

//Assuming that you're returning a string from the userdefaults...
var UserEmail = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userEmail") as? String ?? ""
var userPass = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userPassword") as? String ?? ""
```

The top part allows you to save the variables, and the bottom fetches them.